# Programmatically obtain LILYPOND_DATADIR for execlp() call

Tags: environment-variables, exec

I wrote an application that calls `lilypond` by `execlp()`ing it. However, when my app executes this line, the following error occurs:

```
GNU LilyPond 2.16.2
warning: not relocating, no 2.16.2/ or current/ found under <app_dir>/share/lilypond/
ERROR: In procedure primitive-load-path:
ERROR: Unable to find file "lily.scm" in load path
```

I currently allow my user to inform his/her `lilypond` executable path inside the app. Is there any way I can programmatically set this to values that will always work, no matter where my executable is located?